# Strange behaviour with file_get_contents/file_put_contents

Tags: php

Wanted to write a quick one liner to count page loads, not worrying about users, sessions or refreshes, and tried this:

file_put_contents("page.test", ((file_get_contents("page.test"))+1));

echo "Test:".file_get_contents("page.test");

On every load or refresh, the page.test file increases by 3, not 1 which I expected. If I write each step as a separate line of code and use a counter variable as an intermediate step, then it all works as expected, but the one liner goes up 3 at a time.

Appreciate some wisdom from the experts! Thank you. Ray

Comment: That should not be the case. Try replacing it with `file_put_contents('page.test', round(microtime(), 5) . "\n", FILE_APPEND)` to see if it's not just multi-call consequence

Comment: I commented out my line and put yours in, and it appends 3 times for each refresh, so after two refreshes and the echo output shows:
Test:360.38625 0.38651 0.38668 0.6866 0.68683 0.68697

Comment: OK, it's a mulicall consequence! Thank you and sorry for my bad!

Comment: You can delete your question now then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested that code locally. and no problem with none of theme.
both of theme increased one by one.

be sure you refresh the page just one time !

Comment: Thanks to both yourself and justinas. My bad programming, I'd written the counter line just inside the end of a for loop curly bracket. Must be going blind not to spot it first time round!